# Calculating Strain gauge Values in a tensile Test

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

I got a question on an online quiz which leaves me clueless.
I gave my best to translate the question as accurately as possible:

There's a strain gauge placed upon a tension rod with a rectangular cross section in transverse direction. Which Value does it show at the onset of yielding?
The steel used is mild steel S235 with an E-Module of $E = 210000$ MPa, $µ = 0.3$, yield stress $R_e = 235$ MPa and UTS $R_m = 490$ MPa

Dimension of the Tension Rod: 100mm x 13,4mm x 7,4mm (Length, Width, Depth)

[image: Question]

Comment: Here is a hint, use the relationship between the Poisson's modulus and volume.

Comment: Hello Sam, thanks for the hint. I found a few formulas which include the Posson's modulus and volume, however those are only for tension rods with a circular cross section.

Comment: I assume this problem is a homework, correct me i'm wrong, if so then try $-\nu\frac{\sigma_y}{E}$, with $\sigma_y$ i mean yield stress, the equation is equal to strain in both transverse directions, if and only if we consider S235 to be an isotrope and homogenous material. which is not far from reality